# Append the js code inside js file dynamically and execute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have a code in string format:

```
var str = "var a = 10;b = 20;console.log(a+b);";
```

I need to append this string value to the existing js file(say test.js) dynamically. And also get the result or execute it.
* However, I can load the string in separate  and execute it, but that's not what i need. Thanks for your kind help and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as :

for example in text file you will call a function where you want to append the code as :

test.js ->

```
// some javascript code

myFunction();

// some javascript code
```

Now in main file create this function as :

```
var execuationCode = "var a = 10;b = 20;console.log(a+b);";

function myFunction(){
    setTimeout(execuationCode, 0);
}
```

When nyFunction call in test.js file then it call this main file function

Comment: This executes the code, but do not append the lines to js file

Comment: You can not append the line in js file. We will write complete code for you if you want